# Copying addresses from a list of messages in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts, address-book

OK - so I have a folder full of messages I'd like to reply to. I want to extract the From e-mail addresses, paste them into a spreadsheet and then mail merge these people a new, personalized message. When I just blindly copy the messages and try to drop them into Excel, some contacts are just names and some are e-mail addresses. Is there a way to force Outlook to only display their addresses? If not, is there a better way to get this information out of the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try exporting the message, with the Import/Export Wizard, into a more usable/generic format like .CSV (Comma Separated Values).

You get to the Export Wizard in Outlook 2010, go to `File-->Options-->Advanced-->Export` to open the Import And Export Wizard (I believe `File-->Open-->Import` works as well), and chose "Export to a file".

See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290859) and/or [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/export-outlook-2010-mail-contacts-notes-tasks-and-appointments/) for more info.

I haven't used it, but there's also a beta add-on for Outlook 2010 that is specifically aimed at exporting stuff, with many options.  You can check that out on codeplex.com: [Outlook Data Export 2.0](http://outlookdataexp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Previews&referringTitle=Home&ANCHOR#Outlook%20Data%20Export%202.0)

Comment: Perfect - I didn't know you could export the folder to CSV. thanks!